# Accessing column value of table A using value from table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables say ABC and XYZ,

Table ABC:

```
B   C   ID    ABC_ID
====================
50  30  10     2
60  31  11     3
```

Note: All the value fields are integers.

Table XYZ:

```
group   condition    value   ID
================================
  B         =         50     10
  C         >         30     11
```

Note:

1. Column B and condition are varchar strings and value, ID  columns are integers.
2. Using MySQL 5.5

---

I'm joining both the tables on the basis of column, ID.
There are many values for group in table XYZ and those values are columns in table ABC.

So, my questions are:

1. Once the ID matches, I will get the value of group as B in the above case from table XYZ. Then using the value, how should I get the value of B from table ABC?

   I want to do something like :

   `select A.(X.group) from ABC A join XYZ X on A.ID = X.ID;`
2. Once I'm able to get the value of column B using step 1 (as above), I need to form an expression like (group condition value) e.g. in able case B = 50 and replace the value of B from table ABC in the expression. The formed expression needs to be evaluated and if true, need to return the ABC_id from table ABC. How can I evaluate the expression?

   I'm doing something like this:

   `select A.ABC_ID from XYZ X join ABC A on A.ID = X.ID where X.(A.group) A.condition A.value;`

I've tried using PREPARE'ing and EXECUTE'ing but the join of ABC and XYZ would give multiple rows as a set. And it does not work.

```
SELECT X.group, X.condition, X.value 
from XYZ X join ABC A
on X.ID = A.ID
into @colname, @condition, @value;

SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT * from ABC WHERE ',@colname,@condition,@value);

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you were to create a SQLFiddle of your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sqlfiddle of this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15e205/5

Note that I changed the names of `group` and `condition` because those are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), and really aren't good choices for column names.

I'm using [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to build the query based on the values retrieved in XYZ.

```
SELECT grp, cndition, value 
from XYZ 
where id = 10 
into @colname, @condition, @value;

SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT * from abc WHERE ',@colname,@condition,@value);

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: this will not work if the join of ABC and XYZ on the basis of ID, returns more than one row.